# Как выполнить код после выполнения корутины?

Tags: android, kotlin

Я получаю состояние подписки из google с помощью этого кода:

```
billingClient.startConnection(object : BillingClientStateListener {
override fun onBillingSetupFinished(billingResult: BillingResult) {
    if (billingResult.responseCode == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
        // The BillingClient is ready. You can query purchases here.
    }
}

override fun onBillingServiceDisconnected() {
    // Try to restart the connection on the next request to
    // Google Play by calling the startConnection() method.
}
})

navigateHome()
```

Затем открываю фрагмент с нужными параметрами, в зависимости от того, есть подписка или нет. Но этот код возвращает состояние подписки позже прорисовки фрагмента. Как мне дождаться выполнения кода выше, а затем уже выполнять что-то далее? Пробовал обернуть этот код в корутины с withContext. Всё равно не дожидается.  Пробовал положить в suspend fun. Тоже не получилось.

Comment: не вижу в данном коде корутин, обычный callback. Может открывать ваш фрагмент в onBillingSetupFinished ?

Comment: @IR42 в onBillingSetupFinished мне не подходит, потому что если не законектилось, я этот код вызываю в других местах из функции. И там не нужно, чтобы переходило во фрагмент